# How do I disable cache sweepers for testing purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, observers

I'm using a sweeper to watch a model and do some logging with snogmetrics:

```
class UserSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe User

  def after_create(user)
    km.identify(user.email)
  end
end
```

I'm doing this with a sweeper instead of an observer because snogmetrics needs the session in order to function properly.

However, while testing, snogmetrics utterly fails

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `identify' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I disable the sweeper for unit tests? Thanks!

Comment: It's defined by snogmetrics. https://github.com/iconara/snogmetrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the [no-peeping-toms gem](https://github.com/patmaddox/no-peeping-toms) to block observers during testing.

NOTE: This also works for rake tasks. I had an issue with observers being called during a migration and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `km` defined? From what I see, it's not defined in your user_sweeper so it will fail regardless the environment you're in.